# How do spell check to type the text for TextBox in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, spell-checking

I will try the way of the following code:

```
'Click on Button1 spell checks Text1 textbox
Dim strResultText As String
Dim sc As New SpellChecker
sc.OpenDictionary "c:\SpellUS.lex"
Private Sub Button1_Click()
    TextBox1.Focus()

    strResultText = sc.CheckText(TextBox1.Text, ExitStatus)
    TextBox1.Text = strResultText
End Sub
```

But The above code is error.
1. SpellChecker
2.ExitStatus

I can identify the error.But I don't know.How do fix the error?.So anybody know the problem please help.

Comment: What happens? What is the expected result? This isn’t a real question that can be answered.

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine checking the ExitStatus would give you a clue about the error (if there is one that is)